# Magento getChildHtml() not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php, layout

i want to use one childhtml block to another page, see below screen shot you will get more idea about my question.[image]

page/1column.phtml 
        
        
            Free Legal Advice

```
<flquestion_answer_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action> 
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
                <action method="setTitle"><title>Free Legal Advice</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="flquestion/question_getadvice" name="answer.post"  template="federallawyer/flquestion/form/answer/advice.phtml">

        </block>
    </reference>
</flquestion_answer_index>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want it to go inside the `content` or inside your custom block `answer.post`?

Comment: you can call this `childHtml` only in your `<flquestion_answer_index>` block.

Comment: pleas past code..

Comment: i want it to go inside the my custom block "answer.post"

Comment: Then you are on the right track, yes you should put your block inside `answer.post`

Answer (score 5):

I think you should call

```
echo $this->getBlockHtml('question.search')
```

`getBlockHtml('block_name_here')` get's you the html of the block with name block_name_here if it finds it in the layout...anywhere.

`getChildHtml('block_name_here')` get's you the html of the block with name block_name_here only if that block is a child of the current block.

Comment: i tried with you mentioned way, but still no response.

Answer (score 2):

As per as your image.you want to call `question.search` block as child block of  `answer.post`.

But you have call  `question.search` as it sibling of   of answer.post.

So you need make `answer.post` as `question.search`  reference block and remove from refence content

```
<reference name="answer.post">
<block type="...." name="question.search" ... />
</reference>
```

Comment: no, i like to add the "question.search" as a child block into the "answer.post" block.

Comment: can you please post code in question instead of show at image

Answer (score 2):

On your layout XML, you should put that block inside `answer.post`, like this:

```
<block type="flquestion/question_getadvice" name="answer.post"  template="federallawyer/flquestion/form/answer/advice.phtml">
    <block type="flquestion/form_question_search" name="question.search" template="federalLawyer/flquestion/form/question/search.phtml" />
</block>
```

After that, your `federallawyer/flquestion/form/answer/advice.phtml` template should have this line:

```
$this->getChildHtml('question.search');
```

Put it anywhere you want inside the template.